# How to fix "TypeError: teachingExp.map is not a function", in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**I have 2 dynamic inputs academic and teaching exp but only academic works**
**and when I try to add a new field to teachingExp it returns typeError: teachingExp.map is not a**
**function**
i have used the same code for both dynamic inputs but one works and other does not
both these input divs are inside a form

*outside component return*

```
const [academic, setAcademic] = useState([
    {
      degree: "",
      branch: "",
      university: "",
      completionYear: "",
      grade: "",
    },
  ]);

const [teachingExp, setTeachingExp] = useState([
    {
      university: "",
      designation: "",
      period: "",
    },
  ]);

const handleAcademicChange = (index, e) => {
    let data = [...academic];
    data[index][e.target.id] = e.target.value;
    setAcademic(data);
  };

const handleTeachingExpChange = (index, e) => {
    let data = [...teachingExp];
    data[index][e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    setTeachingExp(data);
  };

const addAcademic = () => {
    let newAcademic = {
      degree: "",
      branch: "",
      university: "",
      completionYear: "",
      grade: "",
    };
    setAcademic([...academic, newAcademic]);
  };

const addTeachingExp = () => {
    let newTeachingExp = {
      university: "",
      designation: "",
      period: "",
    };
    setTeachingExp(...teachingExp, newTeachingExp);
  };

const removeAcademic = (index) => {
    let data = [...academic];
    data.splice(index, 1);
    setAcademic(data);
  };

 const removeTeachingExp = (index) => {
    let data = [...teachingExp];
    data.splice(index, 1);
    setTeachingExp(data);
  };
```

*inside return*

```
<div className="flex justify-center w-full m-auto my-6 p-4 font-sans ">
            <div className="flex flex-col p-3">
              <h3 className="text-center p-3 text-3xl font-medium text-gray-700 mb-5 ">
                Academic Qualifications
              </h3>
              {academic.map((input, index) => {
                return (
                  <div
                    key={index}
                    className="w-56 mb-4 relative group grid place-content-center place-items-center m-auto lg:grid-flow-col  gap-4 "
                  >
                    <div className="w-56 lg:w-40 p-2 xl:w-56">
                      <label className="text-sm font-light">Degree/Title</label>
                      <input
                        className="form-control
        block
        w-full
        px-3
        py-1.5
        text-base
        font-normal
        text-gray-700
        bg-white bg-clip-padding
        border border-solid border-gray-300
        rounded
        transition
        ease-in-out
        m-0
        focus:text-gray-700 focus:bg-white focus:border-blue-600 focus:outline-none "
                        type="text"
                        required
                        id="degree"
                        autoComplete="true"
                        placeholder="Enter degree"
                        value={input.degree}
                        onChange={(e) => handleAcademicChange(index, e)}
                      />
                    </div>
                    <div className="w-56 lg:w-40 p-2 xl:w-56">
                      <label className="text-sm font-light">
                        Branch/Specialization
                      </label>
                      <input
                        className="form-control
        block
        w-full
        px-3
        py-1.5
        text-base
        font-normal
        text-gray-700
        bg-white bg-clip-padding
        border border-solid border-gray-300
        rounded
        transition
        ease-in-out
        m-0
        focus:text-gray-700 focus:bg-white focus:border-blue-600 focus:outline-none "
                        type="text"
                        required
                        id="branch"
                        autoComplete="true"
                        placeholder="Enter branch"
                        value={input.branch}
                        onChange={(e) => handleAcademicChange(index, e)}
                      />
                    </div>

                    <div className="w-56 lg:w-40 p-2 xl:w-56">
                      <label className="text-sm font-light">
                        University/College
                      </label>
                      <input
                        className="form-control
        block
        w-full
        px-3
        py-1.5
        text-base
        font-normal
        text-gray-700
        bg-white bg-clip-padding
        border border-solid border-gray-300
        rounded
        transition
        ease-in-out
        m-0
        focus:text-gray-700 focus:bg-white focus:border-blue-600 focus:outline-none "
                        type="text"
                        required
                        id="university"
                        autoComplete="true"
                        placeholder="Enter university"
                        value={input.university}
                        onChange={(e) => handleAcademicChange(index, e)}
                      />
                    </div>
                    <div className="w-56 lg:w-40 p-2 xl:w-56">
                      <label className="text-sm font-light">
                        Completion year
                      </label>
                      <input
                        className="form-control
        block
        w-full
        px-3
        py-1.5
        text-base
        font-normal
        text-gray-700
        bg-white bg-clip-padding
        border border-solid border-gray-300
        rounded
        transition
        ease-in-out
        m-0
        focus:text-gray-700 focus:bg-white focus:border-blue-600 focus:outline-none "
                        type="text"
                        required
                        id="completedYear"
                        autoComplete="true"
                        placeholder="Enter completion year"
                        value={input.completedYear}
                        onChange={(e) => handleAcademicChange(index, e)}
                      />
                    </div>
                    <div className="w-56 lg:w-40 p-2 xl:w-56">
                      <label className="text-sm font-light">Grade/Marks</label>
                      <input
                        className="form-control
        block
        w-full
        px-3
        py-1.5
        text-base
        font-normal
        text-gray-700
        bg-white bg-clip-padding
        border border-solid border-gray-300
        rounded
        transition
        ease-in-out
        m-0
        focus:text-gray-700 focus:bg-white focus:border-blue-600 focus:outline-none "
                        type="text"
                        required
                        id="grade"
                        autoComplete="true"
                        placeholder="Enter grade"
                        value={input.grade}
                        onChange={(e) => handleAcademicChange(index, e)}
                      />
                    </div>
                    {academic.length > 1 ? (
                      <TrashIcon
                        className="h-8 mt-5 mx-4 text-red-600"
                        onClick={() => removeAcademic(index)}
                      />
                    ) : (
                      ""
                    )}
                  </div>
                );
              })}

              <PlusCircleIcon
                className="h-12 p-2 mx-4 text-[#020493] mt-1"
                onClick={addAcademic}
              />
            </div>
          </div>


<div className="flex justify-center w-full m-auto my-6 p-4 font-sans ">
            <div className="flex flex-col p-3">
              <h3 className="text-center p-3 text-3xl font-medium text-gray-700 mb-5 ">
                Teaching Experience
              </h3>
              {teachingExp.map((input, index) => (
                <div
                  key={index}
                  className="w-56 mb-4 relative group grid place-content-center place-items-center m-auto lg:grid-flow-col  gap-4 "
                >
                  <div className="w-56 lg:w-40 p-2 xl:w-56">
                    <label className="text-sm font-light">
                      University/College
                    </label>
                    <input
                      className="form-control
        block
        w-full
        px-3
        py-1.5
        text-base
        font-normal
        text-gray-700
        bg-white bg-clip-padding
        border border-solid border-gray-300
        rounded
        transition
        ease-in-out
        m-0
        focus:text-gray-700 focus:bg-white focus:border-blue-600 focus:outline-none "
                      type="text"
                      required
                      name="university"
                      autoComplete="true"
                      placeholder="Enter university"
                      value={input.university}
                      onChange={(e) => handleTeachingExpChange(index, e)}
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="w-56 lg:w-40 p-2 xl:w-56">
                    <label className="text-sm font-light">Designation</label>
                    <input
                      className="form-control
        block
        w-full
        px-3
        py-1.5
        text-base
        font-normal
        text-gray-700
        bg-white bg-clip-padding
        border border-solid border-gray-300
        rounded
        transition
        ease-in-out
        m-0
        focus:text-gray-700 focus:bg-white focus:border-blue-600 focus:outline-none "
                      type="text"
                      required
                      name="designation"
                      autoComplete="true"
                      placeholder="Enter designation"
                      value={input.designation}
                      onChange={(e) => handleTeachingExpChange(index, e)}
                    />
                  </div>

                  <div className="w-56 lg:w-40 p-2 xl:w-56">
                    <label className="text-sm font-light">Period</label>
                    <input
                      className="form-control
        block
        w-full
        px-3
        py-1.5
        text-base
        font-normal
        text-gray-700
        bg-white bg-clip-padding
        border border-solid border-gray-300
        rounded
        transition
        ease-in-out
        m-0
        focus:text-gray-700 focus:bg-white focus:border-blue-600 focus:outline-none "
                      type="text"
                      required
                      name="period"
                      autoComplete="true"
                      placeholder="Enter period"
                      value={input.period}
                      onChange={(e) => handleTeachingExpChange(index, e)}
                    />
                  </div>
                  {teachingExp.length > 1 ? (
                    <TrashIcon
                      className="h-8 mt-5 mx-4 text-red-600"
                      onClick={() => removeTeachingExp(index)}
                    />
                  ) : (
                    ""
                  )}
                </div>
              ))}
              <PlusCircleIcon
                className="h-12 p-2 mx-4 text-[#020493] mt-1"
                onClick={addTeachingExp}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not properly updating state when adding new. Rewrite to this:

```
  const addTeachingExp = () => {
    let newTeachingExp = {
      university: "",
      designation: "",
      period: "",
    };
    setTeachingExp([...teachingExp, newTeachingExp]); // HERE YOU FORGOT TO SPREAD IT INTO NEW ARRAY
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Teaching experience is an array by updating state you missed to put it  inside an array

```
Replace that one via 

setTeachingExp(...teachingExp, newTeachingExp);

By this

setTeachingExp([...teachingExp, newTeachingExp]);
```